# How to enable your Windows Script Host through Registry Editor?

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh, win32-process, windows-hosting

The error I'm getting:

[image: IMG of Main Error of this question]

**Windows Script Host access is disabled on this machine. Contact your administrator for details.**

From many websites you can find that making a file named: ["Enabled"] of "DWORD value 32 bit" in the
registry location: `[Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings]`
will solve the issue. Here Changing / setting the value "0" means "Windows Script host is disabled."
and "1" indicated to "enable" it.

Here comes the complexity:
The time you make such file and set to 0, reverting back to old state might not work for you. I set the value back to 1, deleted the file, recreated it. Nothing was working. 20 to 30 websites were telling only to edit the value but not telling anything further. I was becoming paranoid.

If you keep the Windows Script Host disabled, then you cannot see the error message. If any particular script file is causing the error to be triggered, you cannot see except the message "Windows Script Host is Disabled on this machine!".

Comment: If you found the solution, please don't include the solution in the question. Instead answer your own question with the solution you found. Now it's very confusion what part is the question and what part the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. Can you check again, if it is clear or not? If still I need to change, I'll move the solution portion as you suggested.

Comment: >https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-script-host-disabled-machine-contact-administator/

This is the website you can use if you are finding it difficult to understand the problem and the solution. They did the neat work mainly.

Comment: There should be a clear, concise question without hyperbole and a separate clear, concise answer.

Comment: The format of Stackoverflow is quite particular. Its a Question and Answer site. Questions should contain a question only. Anwers only answers. Your current question does not fit the format. It's perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question; but not **in** the question.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a day to find the right solution to enable it:
SRC=
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-script-host-disabled-machine-contact-administator/

Section 4 from the website:
[image: image of section 4 in the website]
"

1. Enable Windows Script Host access using command-line.
2. To do this using command-line, execute these commands from elevated Command Prompt:
   `REG DELETE "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings" /v Enabled /f`

   `REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings" /v Enabled /f`
3. With the Windows Script Host restrictions lifted, you should only run scripts from trusted sources and if you’re sure they are safe to run.

That’s it! This enables Windows Scripting host on your computer.

So, in the command line you'll see:-> "Operation completed successfully!"
[As each command you execute]
Final result: When you click on wscipt.exe, it no longer shows you that error message of being disabled!

Also, the "enabled" file in the given registry path will also be cleaned!
[image: img of registry path cleaned of "enabled" file]

Now I can finally see the error message I messed up and made it worse:

[image: img of wscript message finally being changed!]

My goal was to change the error message from "generalized" to "specific".

From this:

[image: Main Error]

to that:

[image: Specified error]

Remember: Never to hide your problems this way as ignoring the problem will never solve anything!